# Vue disable mobile menu transition on route change?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Is there a way to disable my mobile menu transitions when changing page route within my app? On initial build I noticed the menu would remain open when I would change page route. I then added a route watcher to "close" the menu on page route change which is working however when the page route changes the route changes and then the mobile menu applies its vue transitions and closes after the page has already changed which is not the end of the world but it is a bit janky to me. How do you go about closing the menu and avoiding the transitions?

```
  export default {
      name: "Menu",
      data() {
        return {  
          activeMenu: false,
          menuTransition: null 
        };
      },
  watch: {
    $route() {
      this.activeMenu = false;
    }
  }
    };
```

One of the menu items:

```
 <transition :name="menuTransition">
              <ul
                class="dropdown-menu"
              >
                <li>
                  <router-link to="/page2"
                    >Page 2</router-link
                  >
                </li>
              </ul>
            </transition>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new class `notransition` when the route changes immediately. then remove that class so that transition can work normally.

```
.notransition {
  -webkit-transition: none !important;
  -moz-transition: none !important;
  -o-transition: none !important;
  -ms-transition: none !important;
  transition: none !important;
}
```

Comment: This worked but I realized my problem was not coming from the vue transitions...Will ask another question to solve that one...thank you!